# how to get gcloud auth print-identity-token in ReactJS to request authenticated cloud function?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-functions, token

I am requesting authenticated gcp cloud function from React app, it requires a token in authorization bearer token. I can easily do curl request from cmd but now I want to get the response in react app. Token gets changed after sometime so I cannot hardcode it in my app.

How can I access gcp print-identity-token from frontend (or other token which will do the work)

Comment: Use the node.js SDK. Do not use the CLI to generate tokens unless you like lots of potential issues.

Comment: Which type of account/credential do you have when you want to perform that operation?

Comment: I have service account json file